# IPTABLES DROP not hitting for external devices

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I have a router/gateway that is 10.1.1.1/24 I have a server running Ubunutu server 16.04 with 3 interfaces. 
ens3 = 10.1.1.250/24 (outside)
ens4 = 10.1.2.250/24 (inside)
ens5 = 10.1.3.250/24 (not used yet)
I added one nat table rule to SNAT the ens3 outside interface.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  any    ens3    anywhere             anywhere             to:10.1.1.250
```

using a laptop I set my default gateway to 10.1.2.250 and ip to 10.1.2.22/24 and I am able to ping all server interfaces, the router and out to the internet.

I added a filter rule to drop based on destination ip

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23 packets, 2564 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             151.101.56.193
```

from the server trying to go to that IP, the rule blocks my connection and records count properly, but from my laptop connecting at ens4 I can make it to the site and it does not get blocked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OUTPUT-chain is for packets originated from server itself. Clients' packets should be blocked on FORWARD-chain. Something like this: `iptables -I FORWARD -d 151.101.56.193 -j DROP`.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much for this, I was beating my head trying to figure this out and I knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks for the answer and explaining the packet routing better.